# Should you write the code for the OP?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've seen a couple of answers have sections at the end of the post where it brings together all of the recommendations that have been mentioned in that post and re-writes the code using those recommendations.

Is this okay, or is it better to leave that part up to the OP of the question?

One example of this is [an answer to "The Loaderless Bootloader"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94220/the-loaderless-bootloader/94263#94263).

Comment: possible duplicate of [A code review without the code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5395/a-code-review-without-the-code)

Comment: @RubberDuck I do not believe that this is a duplicate because this question is talking about re-writing the OP's code at the end of an answer, regardless of the answer containing any code before the end.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. It's well established that answers aren't required to include code.

Comment: I understand that. The question is if it's okay to re-write the OP's code for the OP.

Comment: Oh. Sure. Can't see why not. I think it depends on OPs skill level personally. If I think OP is capable of taking some advice and running with it, I won't bother with re-writing code. A lot of times how ever, I think OP needs to actually see how it can be done better. In that case, I'll usually at least put some psuedocode together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Often, when I put together an answer, I copy the OP's code in to my IDE, and then refactor things as I see the problems. Each time I make a change, I add it to my answer as a bullet-item of things that were "wrong".

As I work through the code, I build up my answer. It's then no real effort for me to copy the resulting code back to the answer.

What I am trying to say, is that for me, often, the "summary" code and the actual answer are simultaneously written. Further, I would not be able to write the answer nearly as easily if I could not code the changes and visualize the problems as I go.

So, having done the rewrite just to write the answer, it's no stretch to paste that too.

There is no rule against doing it, and I would rather people and the OP could see the result as I intended it to be without having to cobble things together themselves.

Comment: I do this too and often my reviews have lots of "middle refactorings" leading to the summary code. I find it gives a nice feel for how I got from a to d.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this okay, or is it better to leave that part up to the OP of the question?

Yes, it is okay.

Yes, it *can* be better to leave it to the OP.

It depends really. It is up to you. I don't think there is a "right" way to do it.

I myself tend to do sometimes include some re-written code, sometimes not.

Answer (score 8):

If the question is tagged [homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), then avoid giving away the solution.  Otherwise, how you write your review is up to you.